# My cookie is not set in Browser of studio.apollographql explorer

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, express-session

i am trying to set cookie on apollo Studio explorer, my redis setup successfully store the cookie, but nothing is set on the browser.
Please What am i doing wrong ?
when make a monitoring of redis with redis-cli ,i can see that the token is receive.
i am using : apollo-server-express "^3.3.0", and express-session "^1.17.2"

```
async function startServer() {
  const app = express();
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

  const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
  const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 6379,
  });

  app.use(
    session({
      name: "pid",
      store: new RedisStore({
        client: redisClient,
      }),
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
      },
      saveUninitialized: false,
      secret: "EOJ7OmvIAhb2yJpCI947juj6F8CppHCp",
      resave: false,
    })
  );

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: createContext,
    formatError: (error) => {
      return {
        message: error.message,
      };
    },
  });

  await server.start();

  server.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    cors: { credentials: true, origin: "https://studio.apollographql.com" },
  });

  await new Promise((resolve: any) =>
    httpServer.listen({ port: process.env.PORT }, resolve)
  );
}

startServer().catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: This may be an awkward question, but just to have it asked, how do you know it's not setting a cookie? Your website can't set a cookie on the domain name of studio.apollographql, but it may be setting a cookie on its own domain. If you go to your graphql endpoint directly with the same browser window (you may get the "Cannot GET /" or something), does a cookie show up there?

Comment: Side note: what is the domain of your server? Is this `http://localhost:somePort` (guessing from the redis information)? If so, you're saying your cookie is "secure: true", which means it won't work if you aren't over HTTPS.